# To check whether $(G,*)$ is a group or not if $a_i*a_j=\begin{cases} a_{i+j}, i+j<7\\a_{i+j-7},i+j\geq7\end{cases}$ and $G=\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_6\}$.

Tags: group-theory

This problem is from Herstein's Topics in Algebra. Which states check whether $(G,*)$ is a group or not if $a_i*a_j=\begin{cases} a_{i+j}, i+j<7\\a_{i+j-7},i+j\geq7\end{cases}$ and $G=\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_6\}$.

Now, 1. The closure property ,3. Existence of an identity $a_0$and 4. Existence of the inverse is easily found $(\forall a_i,\exists a_{7-i})$ , these are easily proven or found.

Now the problem is with the 2. Associative property.

I approached this way:

Observe,  $a_i*a_j=a_{i+j-7n}$ ;where $n=0 \implies i+j<7 ...n=1 \implies i+j\geq 7$.

Also observe that ...
$(a_i*a_j)*a_k=a_{i+j+k-14n}$ ....(1)

(Also tried to generalize $\prod_{i}^{m} a_i=a_{(\sum_{i}^m i)-7mn}$)

Now from these we can (can we?) establish
the Associative property.

Any hint, help and or suggestions are welcome. However don't know this problem has been posted here earlier or not.

Comment: Do you know the group $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z,+)?$

Comment: Presumably that exercise in Herstein is **before** anything like $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ or calculaitons mod $7$.

Answer (score 4):

Observe $a_i * a_j = a_{(i+j) \bmod7}$. For associativity we have to show $(a_{i} * a_{j}) * a_k=a_i * (a_{j} * a_k )$. 
We have $(a_i * a_j)* a_k = a_{(i+j) \bmod7}* a_k = a_{((i+j)\bmod7 + k)\bmod7} =a_i*(a_j*a_k)$ , because $((i+j)\bmod 7 + k) \bmod7 = (i+j+k) \bmod7 = (i+(j+k)\bmod7)\bmod7.$

**Edit:** In the proof i made a claim that $ ((i+j)\bmod7+k)\bmod7=(i+(j+k)\bmod7)\bmod7.$ Let me prove it.
Proof : Suppose $t=((i+j)\bmod7+k)\bmod7$. Let $r= (i+j)\bmod7$ which implies $r=7m+i+j$ for some $m \in ℤ $. We have $t=(r+k)\bmod7$, then there exist $n ∈ ℤ $ s.t $t=7n+r+k=7(n+m)+i+j+k$ since $m+n \in ℤ $, thus $t = (i+j+k)\bmod7$. Using similar reasoning we see $(i+j+k)\bmod7=(i+(j+k)\bmod7)\bmod7)$ as desired.

Comment: I think you just translated one associativity statement to another. How would $((i+j) \bmod 7) + k) \bmod 7 = (i+j+k) \bmod 7 + (i + (j+ k)\bmod 7) \bmod 7)$ be proven?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I have edited my solution. Have a look

Comment: Yes, looks good. Please just use `\bmod` instead of `mod` so the formatting looks right.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know [the group $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z,+)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n)? If so, the principle of [transport of structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) completely solves your exercise.

It is a fancy name for the following rather obvious fact (stated here for groups but generalizable to any kind of structure): whenever you have a group $(H,+)$ and a bijection $f:G\to H$, the binary operation $*$ on $G$ defined by
$$a*b:=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))$$
makes $(G,*)$ be a group (and $f$ a group isomorphism).

You can safely apply this to $f(a_k):=k\bmod7.$

Comment: No , I don't know it very well. However I am studying this... Thank you

Comment: Can the today-downvoter please explain how they believe I could improve my answer?